# Function onSubmit does not execute when called from a component inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component in my next.js project that uses NavbarItem component.

NavbarItem component uses Login to render a login form.
This NavbarItem component takes Login component as a parameter to function.

And in this setup, function handleSubmit called by onSubmit inside `<form>` in Login component is not called.

[This is how it looks (both ways properly render Login component)](https://prnt.sc/Ax9KNjj_KHAf)

But when i use directly Login component function handleSubmit works properly, like this:

```jsx
<Login setLoginRenderCount={setLoginRenderCount} />
```

<sub>Login.jsx:</sub>

```
'use client';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
export const Login = ({setLoginRenderCount}) => {
    const [form, setForm] = useState({});

    const handleChange = (e) => { 
      e.preventDefault();
        setForm({
            ...form,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
     };

    const handleSubmit =  (e) => { 
      console.log('inside handleSubmit');
      e.preventDefault();
      
      };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='chat__bottom'>
        <form className='chat__bottom--container' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input className='chat__bottom--container__input' type='text' placeholder='Type Username' onChange={handleChange} name="username" />
          <br />
          <br />

          <input className='chat__bottom--container__input' type='text' placeholder='Type Password' onChange={handleChange} name="password" />
          <br />
          <br />
          
          <button className='chat__bottom--container__btn' type="submit" >Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

---

<sub>NavbarItem.jsx:</sub>

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

export const NavbarItem = ({ href, text, subMenuItems }) => {
  
  return (
    <li className='navbar--list__item'>
      <Link className='link-effect' href={href}>
        <span className='link-effect-inner'>
          <span className='link-effect-l'>
            <span>{text}</span>
          </span>
          <span className='link-effect-r'>
            <span>{text}</span>
          </span>
          <span className='link-effect-shade'>
            <span>{text}</span>
          </span>
        </span>
        {subMenuItems &&
             Array.isArray(subMenuItems) ? (
              <ul className='navbar--list__item--list'>
                {
                  subMenuItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
                  ))
                }
              </ul>
            ) : null
          }
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};
```

---

<sub>Component.jsx:</sub>

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Login} from '/components/Navbar/NavbarAccount/Login';
import { NavbarItem } from '../NavbarItem';


const NavbarAccount = () => {
  const [loginRenderCount, setLoginRenderCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className='navbar-login-container'>
      <NavbarItem href="/" text='Not logged in' 
      subMenuItems={[<Login setLoginRenderCount={setLoginRenderCount} key={'login'} />]} />

      <Login setLoginRenderCount={setLoginRenderCount} key={'11'} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavbarAccount;
```

I did try to call onHandle function but it appears to be working properly when only onSubmit function does not work.

Comment: Looks like a pretty simple typo. Your `NavbarItem` only renders `subMenuItems` if it's an array but you're passing a single component

Comment: Oh yeah it's a typo but only in this SO post. In my project it's properly passed as an component in array: `{[<Login setLoginRenderCount={setLoginRenderCount} key={'login'} />]}`. Also they asArray check can be omitted.
Anyway it renders properly in both cases but the submit button does not call onSubmit function

Comment: So how do you know that the function isn't called? You're not using / displaying `loginRenderCount` anywhere

Comment: There is no output from handleSubmit function. I am assuming it is not called because when i did console.log() inside it did not work. But when Login component is rendered directly (not as a props to NavbarItem) this function is called properly (i can see console.log output). I'll edit my Login.jsx code and put there a console.log (deleted it before posing).

Comment: Your import path for `Login` doesn't look right. Paths should not start with `/`

Comment: I cannot reproduce any such issue ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-nobel-2d9rmv?file=/src/NavbarAccount.jsx

Comment: As for `Login` import it does not work either way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256547/discussion-between-wojciech-paraniuk-and-phil).

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered workaround. I changed the way to call `handleClick` function.

Login.jsx:

```
        <form className='chat__bottom--container' >
          <input className='chat__bottom--container__input' type='text' placeholder='Type Username' onChange={handleChange} name="username" />
          <br />
          <br />

          <input className='chat__bottom--container__input' type='text' placeholder='Type Password' onChange={handleChange} name="password" />
          <br />
          <br />
          
          <button className='chat__bottom--container__btn' type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Login</button>
        </form>
```

So basically now button has onClick property that call function which is working!
Seems to be an issue with this specific environment and only when button is trying to submit form.